# how to install an ipa file on an IPAD

Tags: ios, xcode, installation, ipa

I exported my app to an IPA File from XCODE.
I dragdropped this IPA File into ITunes with my Ipad connected.
I clicked on "install" of the app icon and pressed synchronize.

I see an icon appearing on my Ipad with an install animation (I guess). The Icon is a default one and is not that Icon I have set.
I can see the correct name under the Icon.

BUT:
I can't start the app. When clicking on it it writes Installation... under the Icon.

Is my approach worng. If not, what could be the reason ?

**Solved**

I used a provisioning profile for AppleStore insteed of an Adhoc.

Comment: Have you dragdropped also the provisioning profile? Is your iPad enabled for development?

Comment: Hi , Thanks for helping. My fault. I used a provisioning profile for AppleStore insteed of an Adhoc.

Comment: @mcflysoft you're not really new to Stackoverflow so you should now how things work here. Please post your solution as an actual _answer_, not an edit to your _question_.

Comment: Yes I have done this now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:

It was my own fault.
I used a provisioning profile for AppleStore insteed of an Adhoc.
When creating an Adhoc provisioning profile and archiving the app for importing into Itunes and finally synced it to my IPAD. It worked.